# Unable to access value of attribute with dash in PHP using simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to fetch some html values with PHP Simple HTML DOM  and store them in an PHP array.

Inside the HTML page I want to parse/fetch the following :

```
<li id="1" data-name="Jason" class="result-names">
<li id="2" data-name="John" class="result-names">
<li id="3" data-name="Elco" class="result-names">
<li id="5" data-name="Dana" class="result-names">
```

I am able to capture the "id" value and the "class" value, but at this moment I can't seem to get the value of "data-name". The code I am using for trying to achieve this :

```
<?php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$dom = file_get_html('http://localhost/names.html');
foreach($dom->find('li[class=result-names]') as $results) {
    $item['id']     = $results->id;
    $item['name'] = $results->data-name;          //this does not work 
    $item['class'] = $results->class;
    $articles[] = $item;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($articles);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: FYI , why using  $item['class'] = $results->class;   when you know class is "result-names"  , use it directly  $item['class'] = "result-names";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
$item['name'] = $results->getAttribute("data-name");
```

`-` is the subtraction operator, it can't be used as part of an identifier. What you write is parsed as:

```
$item['name'] = ($results->data) - name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
$item['name'] = $results->attr['data-name'];
```